# How to convert a jquery form object to FormData?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting a jquery object like this

```
var form = $("#form1");
```

How do I convert that to FormData object? Do I have to get the html out of the jquery form and then loop through all the input types and do it or is there a more robust way of doing it?

Comment: $("#form1").serialize();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]); // Create an arbitrary FormData instance

jQuery.ajax('/endpoint.php', {
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formData
});
```

refer to [mattlunn blogs](https://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2012/05/sending-formdata-with-jquery-ajax/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
var data = $('#form').serializeArray().reduce(function(obj, item) {
obj[item.name] = item.value;
return obj;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy.
You just need using the default constructor of FormData.

```
var myForm = $("#form")[0];
var formData = new FormData(myForm);
```

The code above can fetch what you want.